# word 2013 to pdf; custom page, margins, background color leaves blank area

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, colors

word 2013
background color set via design -> page color
custom page size is 12.58w x 9.25 ht
margins are 0 on all sides.

in my so-called full page view, the background fills the whole 12.58x9.25 pages.  but when i either export to pdf or print to pdf, the background does NOT fill the output page.
print options:  print background and pictures is turned on.

Comment: Please write whole sentences, this is really a pain to read. Also: Have you tried a PDF printer plugin?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the issue is the custom page size.  ie, if i use
an over-large size page then i can fill the over-large page entirely.
in my case, the excess will be chopped off properly by external software--
that is, once i hand off my file someone downstream can deal with the
surplus.  i don't even know what that downstream software is.

my work flow problem is solved.  but it doesn't seem reasonable that
a i can't export/print from word into a pdf file that has the proper
custom page size.  this is word 2013.  maybe i don't have enough plugins
or whatever, or maybe i just can't find the place where i set the output
page size, but...  whatever it is, i can't make it happen.

but i have a work-around for now.
thx.